# How do I monitor a file system event within a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

How can I monitor a change to a file system (or other external event) in real time using a Shiny app? For example, suppose I have a dashboard app that provides statistics on files located on the server. I would like to update my statistics in real time as those files change or new ones are added.

My thought is to use Javascript on the client to regularly poll the server. Every 10 seconds, e.g., I might call `Shiny.setInputValue("check.fs", 1, {priority: "event"});` and then on the server I'd have `observeEvent(input$check.fs, { ... })`, which would update reactives.

Any other ideas? Is there any way to do this only on the server without javascript?

Comment: This question has now an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098978/reactive-monitoring-of-a-file-in-shiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shiny has a function called `invalidatelater` with wich you can invalidate a given reactive context. This makes it possible to reevaluate a function with a certain interval.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/invalidateLater.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Use reactive file reader

Given a file path and read function, returns a reactive data source for the contents of the file.

https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/reference/reactiveFileReader.html