# Reactive monitoring of a file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app where I need to monitor a file(s) for changes. I should also note these changes do not occur continuously, but rather only several times during a session (there could also be instances when none of the files changes). However I am struggling to do this.

Consider the following example:

```
library(shiny)
```

A function that returns the modified date of a file:

```
file_info <- function(){
  if(file.exists("example.txt")){
    return(as.character(as.Date(file.info("example.txt")[1,4])))
  } else {
    return("File not present")
  }
}
```

Shiny part:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  textOutput("file_status"),
  actionButton("create_file", "Create file"),
  actionButton("delete_file", "Delete file")
))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  file_st <- reactive(file_info()) #what is the correct approach here?
  
  output$file_status <- renderText({
    file_st()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$create_file,{
    file.create("example.txt")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_file, {
    unlink("example.txt")
  })
  
})
```

I would like the `file_status` text field to update each time the `example.txt` file changes - if possible even if this happens outside of the app.

I have tried various combinations of `reactive`, `observe` and `reactiveValues` without finding the adequate combo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I monitor a file system event within a Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492244/how-do-i-monitor-a-file-system-event-within-a-shiny-app)

Comment: @pietrodito `invalidatelater` could be an option, I haven't tested it since `reactivePoll` achieves the desired in a more direct way. `reactiveFileReader` is I think a good option when the monitored file continuously changes. In my case the files of interest do not change continuously so I think  `reactivePoll` is better suited for me (detect if change occurred and only then read files).

Comment: `reactiveFileReader` is just a wrapper around `reactivePoll`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `reactivePoll` which is practically tailored for this type of task

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  file_st <- reactivePoll(500, session,
                          checkFunc = function() {
                            if (file.exists("example.txt"))
                              file.info("example.txt")$mtime[1]
                            else
                              ""},
                          valueFunc = function(){
                            if(file.exists("example.txt")){
                              return(as.character(as.Date(file.info("example.txt")[1,4])))
                            } else {
                              return("File not present")
                            }
                          }
  )
  
  output$file_status <- renderText({
    file_st()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$create_file,{
    file.create("example.txt")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_file, {
    unlink("example.txt")
  })
  
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  textOutput("file_status"),
  actionButton("create_file", "Create file"),
  actionButton("delete_file", "Delete file")
))
```